# React/Redux in a non-single page app - calling multiple dispatch functions on particular route

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm slowly converting a large web app to from jQuery to React/Redux. The app is built in Python and has proper routes that trigger hard refreshes. How do I dispatch Redux actions on particular routes only? I can get it to work for only one action, but I need to fire multiple in some cases. For example, on the content listing page I need to fire a call to the API to return all content (which works fine). When clicking through to edit a piece of content I need to fire a separate API that returns only the selected piece of content plus a metadata API that fills in various select inputs with options.

If I format it like so only the first call appears to work:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

import { loadAllContent, loadSpecificContent } from './actions/myContentActions';
import { loadMetadata } from './actions/metadataActions';

import App from './components/App';
import MyContentPage from './components/MyContent/MyContentPage';
import ManageContentPage from './components/MyContent/ManageContentPage';

export const store = configureStore();

export const routes = (
  <Route path={'/'} component={App}>
    // This page works fine as only one dispatch
    <Route
      path={'/my-content'}
      component={MyContentPage}
      onEnter={() => store.dispatch(loadAllContent())}
    />
    // This page fires the first function fine but not the second
    <Route
      path={'/my-content/:id'}
      component={ManageContentPage}
      // dispatch multiple actions here
      onEnter={() => store.dispatch(loadSpecificContent(), loadMetadata('ages'))}
    />
  </Route>
);
```

Comment: you mean, here you want to call multiple dispatch actions: `onEnter={() =>....`  correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per **[MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)**:

> var func = x => x * x;                     //concise syntax, implied
>   "return"
>
> var func = (x, y) => { return x + y; };  //with block body, explicit
>   "return" needed

Use `{}` with [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) it will create a body and put all the dispatch action inside that.

Like this:

```
onEnter={() => {
      store.dispatch(loadSpecificContent());
      store.dispatch(loadMetadata('ages'));
}}
```